# A government in Asia wants to pass a law making it illegal to use a VPN

Tags: vpn

So how do I still remain anonymous?  Will TOR or Tails prevent this?  Or is Tor or Tails considered a VPN?  At any rate, if the law passes, how to I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use obfs4 bridges. You can use https://bridges.torproject.org/ (most recommended), but if you are too scared or this website is blocked, try to send e-mail from Gmail.com, riseup.net or Yahoo.com to the bridges@torproject.org. To get Tor Browser as last resort method, you can try gettor@torproject.org with typing windows, osx or linux in the body of e-mail message. It is very important to verify integrity of Tor Browser, because you downloading it from Dropbox. [Official verification guide](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en)